# Memory Allocation for a Map with a fixed number of insertions

Tags: c++, memory, stl, dictionary, allocation

I want to insert n elements into a map where n is known ahead of time. I do not want memory allocation at each insertion. I want all memory allocation at the beginning. Is there a way to do this? If so, how? Will writing some sort of memory allocator help?

I ran GMan's code and got the following output. GetMem is printed from a call to "new" and FreeMem is printed from a call to delete. size is the number of bytes requested and ptr is the pointer returned. Clearly, allocation/deallocation is going on during insertion. How do you explain this?

GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420038
GetMem size 120, ptr 0x8420068
GetMem size 120, ptr 0x84200e8
FreeMem ptr 0x8420068
FreeMem ptr 0x8420038
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
Inserting: [0,0]
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
Inserting: [1,2]
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
Inserting: [2,4]
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
Inserting: [3,6]
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
Inserting: [4,8]
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
Inserting: [5,10]
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
GetMem size 40, ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x8420008
FreeMem ptr 0x84200e8
St9bad_alloc

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", get it simply correct and then optimize if measurement tells you it is needed. You are guessing at the performance of map at the design stage; that's premature.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that the question is about memory fragmentation and we are talking about numbers in millions.

Comment: Understood, but then you are also making ante hoc predictions about memory fragmentation and its impact.

Comment: This is not ad hoc. You allocate a piece here for insertion, a piece there for something else, and repeat. By the time you get rid of the map you have holes all over. If you have an answer to the problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Definite not ad hoc. First thing we do in a game engine is re-implement memory allocation.

Comment: What is your usage pattern in this map? Is it first only inserts to build the map and then only searches afterwards or is it random inserts and searches?
If it's the first situation you could just store your data sorted in an array and do the lookups using binary search.

Answer (score 4):

#### Response to allocation test

Add this to either of the samples I give below:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void* allocate(size_t pAmount)
{
    std::cout << "Allocating " << pAmount << " bytes." << std::endl;

    return std::malloc(pAmount);
}

void deallocate(void* pPtr)
{
    std::cout << "Deallocating." << std::endl;

    std::free(pPtr);
}

void* operator new(size_t pAmount) // throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    return allocate(pAmount);
}

void *operator new[](size_t pAmount) // throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    return allocate(pAmount);
}

void *operator new(size_t pAmount, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    return allocate(pAmount);
}

void *operator new[](size_t pAmount, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    return allocate(pAmount);
}

void operator delete(void* pMemory) throw()
{
    deallocate(pMemory);
}

void operator delete[](void* pMemory) throw()
{
    deallocate(pMemory);
}

void operator delete(void* pMemory, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    deallocate(pMemory);
}

void operator delete[](void* pMemory, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    deallocate(pMemory);
}
```

(Note, these are not fully correct replacements of the allocation operators, and are for demonstration.)

Running the runtime-sized sample program gives me the following output:

> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Deallocating.
> Deallocating.
> Allocating 120 bytes.
> Deallocating.
> Allocating 20 bytes.
> Deallocating.
> Allocating 40 bytes.
> Deallocating.
> Deallocating.
> Deallocating.
> Inserting: [0,0]
> Inserting: [1,2]
> Inserting: [2,4]
> Inserting: [3,6]
> Inserting: [4,8]
> Deallocating.
> Deallocating.
> Deallocating.
> bad allocation

Note there are no allocations once insertion has begun. You should be getting *no* memory allocations. How are you generating your output?

---

#### The allocators

What you need is a new allocator. Here's something I made now, so it's relatively untested, but it looks good to me.

It creates a [freelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) and uses that to give out memory. Construction of the allocator takes O(N), but both allocations and deallocations are O(1). (Very fast!) Also, once it's constructed, no more memory allocations take place. Though freelists have average locality, it probably beats what you'd normally get out of a map with the default allocator.

Here it is:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// gets rid of "unused parameter" warnings
#define USE(x) (void)(x)

template <typename T, size_t N>
class freelist_allocator
{
public: 
    // types
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const T const_value_type;
    
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const_value_type& const_reference;
    
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const_value_type* const_pointer;

    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    // ensure it can hold both a pointer and T
    struct block_type
    {
        char data[sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*) ?
                    sizeof(T) : sizeof(void*)];
    };

    typedef std::vector<block_type> buffer_type;

    // constants
    static const size_t Elements = N;

    // rebind
    template<typename U, size_t M = Elements>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef freelist_allocator<U, M> other;
    };

    // constructor
    freelist_allocator(void) :
    mBuffer(Elements),
    mNext(0)
    {
        build_list();
    }

    freelist_allocator(const freelist_allocator&) :
    mBuffer(Elements),
    mNext(0)
    {
        build_list();
    }

    template<typename U, size_t M>
    freelist_allocator(const freelist_allocator<U, M>&) :
    mBuffer(Elements),
    mNext(0)
    {
        build_list();
    }

    // address
    pointer address(reference r)
    {
        return &r;
    }

    const_pointer address(const_reference r)
    {
        return &r;
    }

    // memory
    pointer allocate(size_type pCount, const void* = 0)
    {
        USE(pCount); // pCount unused when assert is disabled in release
        assert(pCount == 1 && "freelist_allocator is noncontiguous");

        // end of list
        if (!mNext)
            throw std::bad_alloc();

        // remove from list
        void* memory = mNext;
        mNext = data_as_ptr(*mNext);

        return static_cast<pointer>(memory);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer pPtr, size_type)
    {
        // get back our block
        block_type* b = reinterpret_cast<block_type*>(pPtr);

        // reinsert to list
        data_as_ptr(*b) = mNext;
        mNext = b;
    }

    // size
    size_type max_size(void) const
    {
        static const size_t MaxSize = 
                    std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
        return MaxSize / sizeof(value_type);
    }

    // construction / destruction
    void construct(pointer pPtr, const T& pT)
    {
        new (pPtr) T(pT);
    }

    void destroy(pointer pPtr)
    {
        USE(pPtr); // trivial destructor skips next line
        pPtr->~value_type();
    }   

private:
    // utility
    block_type*& data_as_ptr(block_type& pBlock)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<block_type*&>(pBlock.data);
    }

    void build_list(void)
    {
        // build list
        for (size_t i = 1; i < mBuffer.size(); ++i)
        {
            data_as_ptr(mBuffer[i - 1]) = &mBuffer[i];
        }

        mNext = &mBuffer[0];
    }

    // members
    buffer_type mBuffer;
    block_type* mNext;
};

// equality
template<typename T, size_t N>
bool operator==(freelist_allocator<T, N> const&,
                freelist_allocator<T, N> const&)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
bool operator!=(freelist_allocator<T, N> const& pX,
                freelist_allocator<T, N> const& pY)
{
    return !(pX == pY);
}

#undef USE
```

And use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

static const size_t MaxElements = 5;

typedef std::pair<int, int> pair_type;
typedef freelist_allocator<pair_type, MaxElements> allocator_type;
typedef std::map<int, int,
                    std::less<int>, allocator_type> map_type;

void do_insert(int pX, int pY, map_type& pMap)
{
    std::cout << "Inserting: [" << pX << ","
        << pY << "]" << std::endl;

    pMap.insert(std::make_pair(pX, pY));
}

int main(void)
{   
    try
    {
        map_type m;

        // just keep inserting
        for (int i = 0; i <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max() / 2; ++i)
        {
            // will throw at MaxElements insertions
            do_insert(i, i * 2, m);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

<strike>For now I've made the size a compile-time constant, but you want a run-time version just let me know and I'll write that up.</strike> Here's a version that takes a size at run-time:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// gets rid of "unused parameter" warnings
#define USE(x) (void)(x)

template <typename T>
class freelist_allocator
{
public: 
    // types
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const T const_value_type;
    
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const_value_type& const_reference;
    
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const_value_type* const_pointer;

    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    // ensure it can hold both a pointer and T
    struct block_type
    {
        char data[sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*) ?
                    sizeof(T) : sizeof(void*)];
    };

    typedef std::vector<block_type> buffer_type;

    // rebind
    template<typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef freelist_allocator<U> other;
    };

    // constructor
    freelist_allocator(size_t pElements) :
    mBuffer(pElements),
    mNext(0)
    {
        build_list();
    }

    freelist_allocator(const freelist_allocator& pRhs) :
    mBuffer(pRhs.size()),
    mNext(0)
    {
        build_list();
    }

    template<typename U>
    freelist_allocator(const freelist_allocator<U>& pRhs) :
    mBuffer(pRhs.size()),
    mNext(0)
    {
        build_list();
    }

    // address
    pointer address(reference r)
    {
        return &r;
    }

    const_pointer address(const_reference r)
    {
        return &r;
    }

    // memory
    pointer allocate(size_type pCount, const void* = 0)
    {
        USE(pCount); // pCount unused when assert is disabled in release
        assert(pCount == 1 && "freelist_allocator is noncontiguous");

        // end of list
        if (!mNext)
            throw std::bad_alloc();

        // remove from list
        void* memory = mNext;
        mNext = data_as_ptr(*mNext);

        return static_cast<pointer>(memory);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer pPtr, size_type)
    {
        // get back our block
        block_type* b = reinterpret_cast<block_type*>(pPtr);

        // reinsert to list
        data_as_ptr(*b) = mNext;
        mNext = b;
    }

    // size
    size_type max_size(void) const
    {
        static const size_t MaxSize = 
                    std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
        return MaxSize / sizeof(value_type);
    }

    size_t size(void) const
    {
        return mBuffer.size();
    }

    // construction / destruction
    void construct(pointer pPtr, const T& pT)
    {
        new (pPtr) T(pT);
    }

    void destroy(pointer pPtr)
    {
        USE(pPtr); // trivial destructor skips next line
        pPtr->~value_type();
    }   

private:
    // utility
    block_type*& data_as_ptr(block_type& pBlock)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<block_type*&>(pBlock.data);
    }

    void build_list(void)
    {
        // build list
        for (size_t i = 1; i < mBuffer.size(); ++i)
        {
            data_as_ptr(mBuffer[i - 1]) = &mBuffer[i];
        }

        mNext = &mBuffer[0];
    }

    // members
    buffer_type mBuffer;
    block_type* mNext;
};

// equality
template<typename T>
bool operator==(freelist_allocator<T> const&,
                freelist_allocator<T> const&)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
bool operator!=(freelist_allocator<T> const& pX,
                freelist_allocator<T> const& pY)
{
    return !(pX == pY);
}

#undef USE
```

Use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

static const size_t MaxElements = 5;

template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct map_types // helpful
{
    typedef std::pair<Key, Value> pair_type;
    typedef freelist_allocator<pair_type> allocator_type;
    typedef std::less<Key> predicate_type;
    typedef std::map<Key, Value,
                    predicate_type, allocator_type> map_type;
};

template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Map>
void do_insert(const Key& pX, const Value& pY, Map& pMap)
{
    std::cout << "Inserting: [" << pX << ","
                << pY << "]" << std::endl;

    pMap.insert(std::make_pair(pX, pY));
}

int main(void)
{   
    try
    {
        typedef map_types<int, int> map_types;

        // double parenthesis to avoid vexing parse
        map_types::map_type m((map_types::predicate_type()),
                            map_types::allocator_type(MaxElements));

        // just keep inserting
        for (int i = 0; i <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max() / 2; ++i)
        {
            do_insert(i, i * 2, m);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The run-time version could possibly allocate more space if there are no more remaining slots, which can be useful. But I leave that to you. (Don't resize the vector! You'll possibly lose your entire buffer. You'll need a `list` of vectors, likely.)

Note if you can use Boost, they have such an allocator in their [Pool library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html). That said, their allocator keeps track of the order you request memory, to ensure reverse construction destruction order. This turns allocations and deallocations into O(N). (A terrible choice in my opinion.) I actually wrote my own allocator around `boost::pool<>` to get around this.

Comment: I've just been fooling around with allocators recently, so thanks for the example! Since containers receive no guarantee that the allocator argument is parameterized in any particular way, would it be better to pass in a `freelist_allocator<char,N>` to minimize the bogus buffer in the temporary object? (Large allocations can take time.) Or specialize it on `void` to avoid any allocation, so only the rebound object creates a pool. Just a thought.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that the allocator argument to a container determines its `pointer` and `reference` types, which relate to the the members of sequence containers but apparently not associative containers like `map` here. Is there a good, preferably free, reference for this stuff?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the number of items for insertion to be chosen at run time.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No clue :/ I mostly just read the standard to see the requirements it has to fulfill, but I know there are some articles online about them.

Comment: The map is stored as a tree. Where does the space for tree pointers come from?

Comment: @prasoon99: Containers will use the `rebind` functionality of of allocator to get their own allocator for internals. That is, it has two allocators, one for just the space needed for data, and one for nodes. This is why you can only guarantee no more memory allocations until the map construction is complete. We actually build a list twice. (Note no memory is wasted though, it's just been split in two different parts.)

Comment: I did the printouts exactly as you suggested. (I was doing it the same way in any case.) No change in my output. What are your compile an link flags?

Comment: @prasoon99: I have this: http://pastebin.com/2ug2rw4A in a default Win32 Console Project in Visual Studio 2008, and I get the output above. That said, I tried it with `g++ main.cpp` with gcc version 4.4.0, and am getting output similar to yours. I find that strange, and wrong. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hashtable. `unordered_map` might be inappropriate as it allows each object to be allocated separately, and uses "closed addressing" with buckets instead of one flat block of memory.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing for a description of the kind of structure you should consider. It's not too difficult to implement an associative container with constant access time and constant insertion time.

Support for deletion can be a little messy, though, and you will need to allocate considerable empty space in the hash table, perhaps double what you actually use, to keep the address space uncluttered.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't required for a `map` the way it's required for a `vector`. Since `map` is implemented as a tree internally, insertions are cheap (you don't move around whole chunks). On the other hand, for a `vector` insertions that take it over the currently reserved bound require to move all the previously allocated elements.

That said, if allocation performance is super crucial to you, you *can* write a custom allocator that, say, allocates from a pre-allocated buffer. If you implement this correctly, it will be faster than the default `new` used by `map`. However, I doubt you must go this far.

Comment: I don't want to fragment the memory by allocating small chunks at each insertion.

Comment: @prasoon99: you won't - the memory allocator of the C runtime isn't stupid, you know :-) But you can probably make it a bit faster using my advice in the 2nd paragraph. Also see the chapter on small object allocations in "Modern C++ Design"

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` doesn't provide any built in support for doing this. But, if the number of elements is small enough, then you can create `std::vector` of pairs and use `vector::reserve` method to reserve the needed space.